# 7 fetch_assoc in a while fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table, fetch

I hope you're having a great day. I have a drag and drop system
in my website and basically it's a website for schemes for residents. If you want to make a new
scheme you have a list of pictogrammen (icons) and you drag the icons that represent activities
next to each of the residents. Now the inserting perfectly works but showing the data does not.

This is my tables structure:

**1. Schemes:**

- IDScheme
- Weekday
- Resident (INDEX -> IDResident)
- Activity (INDEX -> IDActivity)
- Rangnr (From 1 to 7 because there are 7 activities per resident per day)
- Datum

**2. Residents (=bewoners):**

- IDResident
- Foto
- ...

**3. Activities (=pictogrammen):**

- IDActivity
- Icon

Pretty much this is what I need to display the data. As you can see the "Schemes" table is the
main one. Now for me to display the schemes, It will happen via an HTML-table. Let me jump 
straight into the code: Rangnr is basically the place where the activity (icon) is

```
<div id="MainDiv">
  <div id="ListBewoners">
      <table id="ListBewonersUL">                                          
          <?php                                      
          $sql = "SELECT *
                  FROM ActiviteitenSchema A, Bewoners B
                  WHERE A.Bewoner = B.IDBewoner  
                  GROUP BY Bewoner
                  ";

      $sqlrang1 = "SELECT * FROM ActiviteitenSchema A, Pictogrammen P 
                  WHERE P.IDPictogram = A.Activiteit AND Rangnr = 1 
                  AND DatumAangemaakt = $datumAangemaakt";
      $sqlrang2 = "SELECT * FROM ActiviteitenSchema A, Pictogrammen P 
                  WHERE P.IDPictogram = A.Activiteit AND Rangnr = 2 
                  AND DatumAangemaakt = $datumAangemaakt";
      $sqlrang3 = "SELECT * FROM ActiviteitenSchema A, Pictogrammen P 
                  WHERE P.IDPictogram = A.Activiteit AND Rangnr = 3
                  AND DatumAangemaakt = $datumAangemaakt";
      $sqlrang4 = "SELECT * FROM ActiviteitenSchema A, Pictogrammen P 
                  WHERE P.IDPictogram = A.Activiteit AND Rangnr = 4
                  AND DatumAangemaakt = $datumAangemaakt";
      $sqlrang5 = "SELECT * FROM ActiviteitenSchema A, Pictogrammen P 
                  WHERE P.IDPictogram = A.Activiteit AND Rangnr = 5 
                  AND DatumAangemaakt = $datumAangemaakt";
      $sqlrang6 = "SELECT * FROM ActiviteitenSchema A, Pictogrammen P 
                  WHERE P.IDPictogram = A.Activiteit AND Rangnr = 6 
                  AND DatumAangemaakt = $datumAangemaakt";
      $sqlrang7 = "SELECT * FROM ActiviteitenSchema A, Pictogrammen P 
                  WHERE P.IDPictogram = A.Activiteit AND Rangnr = 7 
                  AND DatumAangemaakt = $datumAangemaakt";

      $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); 
      $resRang1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlrang1);
      $resRang2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlrang2);
      $resRang3 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlrang3);
      $resRang4 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlrang4);
      $resRang5 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlrang5);
      $resRang6 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlrang6);
      $resRang7 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlrang7);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
      ?>
      <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row["IDBewoner"] ?></td>  
          <td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['Foto']) . '" width="90" height="90">'  ?></td>
      <?php                
          $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resRang1);
          $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resRang2);
          $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resRang3);
          $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resRang4);
          $row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resRang5);
          $row6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resRang6);
          $row7 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resRang7);

          ?>
      <!-- Rang1 Controle --> 
      <?php 
          if(!empty($row1)) {
      ?>
          <td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row1['Pictogram']) . '" width="90" height="90">' ?></td>
      <?php 
          } else {
      ?> 
          <td><?php echo "Empty"; ?></td>
      <?php        
          }
      ?>

      <!-- Rang2 Controle -->    
      <?php 
          if(!empty($row2)) {
      ?>
          <td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row2['Pictogram']) . '" width="90" height="90">' ?></td>
      <?php
          } else { 
      ?>
          <td><?php echo "Empty2"; ?></td>
      <?php  
          }
      ?>

      <!-- Rang3 Controle -->    
      <?php 
          if(!empty($row3)) {
      ?>
          <td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row3['Pictogram']) . '" width="90" height="90">' ?></td>
      <?php
          } else { 
      ?>
          <td><?php echo "Empty3"; ?></td>
      <?php  
          }
      ?>

      <!-- Rang4 Controle -->    
      <?php 
          if(!empty($row4)) {
      ?>
          <td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row4['Pictogram']) . '" width="90" height="90">' ?></td>
      <?php
          } else { 
      ?>
          <td><?php echo "Empty4"; ?></td>
      <?php  
          }
      ?>

      <!-- Rang5 Controle -->    
      <?php 
          if(!empty($row5)) {
      ?>
          <td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row5['Pictogram']) . '" width="90" height="90">' ?></td>
      <?php
          } else { 
      ?>
          <td><?php echo "Empty5"; ?></td>
      <?php  
          }
      ?>

      <!-- Rang6 Controle -->    
      <?php 
          if(!empty($row6)) {
      ?>
          <td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row6['Pictogram']) . '" width="90" height="90">' ?></td>
      <?php
          } else { 
      ?>
          <td><?php echo "Empty6"; ?></td>
      <?php  
          }
      ?>

      <!-- Rang7 Controle -->    
      <?php 
          if(!empty($row7)) {
      ?>
          <td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row7['Pictogram']) . '" width="90" height="90">' ?></td>
      <?php
          } else { 
      ?>
          <td><?php echo "Empty7"; ?></td>
      <?php  
          }
      ?>

      </tr>
      <?php                                                   
          }
      ?>

  </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

As a result, this how the data looks like:
[image: Displaying the data using the above code]

But the problem is, this is how I inserted them (sorry a little css problem):
[image: Excuse me about the design]

**The problem:** The inserted data are perfectly good inserted and I've checked them in the database, but displaying
them is not working as it should be. Is there a better way of fetching the table 8 times? Because
Apparently my code doesn't really work.

Comment: You should be using _one_ database query, and a loop to output the data …

Comment: @CBroe Can you show me an example please?

Comment: If you don't use an `ORDER BY` clause in your queries, the order of the result rows is totally unpredictable. It doesn't necessarily return them in the order that they were inserted. If you want them in that order, you should include an ID column that uses `auto_increment`, and then use `ORDER BY id` in the SQL.

Comment: @Barmar Will it be ok if I `ORDER BY Rangnr`?

Comment: `Rangnr` is the same for all the rows in each query.

Comment: @CBroe Sir I can't use one database query. I need 8 queries to show up the data. 
One main query that shows the residents and their id's, and the 7 other queries are for the rangnr.
In php it's like that `echo $row["Photo"]` and I need to tell what rangnr it is, and I can only do that via a mysql statement `WHERE Rangnr = 1, 2, ..` to 7.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as some comments pointed, you can grab the data in one query and loop through it.

All you need to mantain the order of when they where inserted is use an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT P.Pictogram, A.Rangnr
FROM ActiviteitenSchema A
INNER JOIN Pictogrammen P ON P.IDPictogram = A.Activiteit
WHERE DatumAangemaakt = $datumAangemaakt
ORDER BY A.Rangnr ASC
```

This way you can write the result in a loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    if(!is_null($row["Pictogram"])) {
        ?>
        <td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['Pictogram']) ?>" width="90" height="90"></td>
       <?php 
    } else {
        ?> 
        <td>Empty <?php echo $row["Rangnr"] ?></td>
        <?php        
    }
}
```

Comment: And how should I be getting this?
`<tr>
          <td><?php echo $row["IDBewoner"] ?></td>  
          <td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['Foto']) . '" width="90" height="90">'  ?></td> `
I need to get the id of the residents from another table

Comment: I need to select the `IDBewoner` & `Foto` too

Comment: This would be basic SQL syntax. you can use `JOIN`s to get the infor you want. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html